# Jquery Countdown Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, countdown

I want to redirect my page as soon as the countdown turns (the end date and current date is same).
I have been using a Jquery Plugin that is beautiful but they have not mentioned the callback function to do so. Now I have to pass function to the Jquery Plugin Can someone help me on how to pass function while calling the plugin. This is my code

```
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
    'start': <?php echo  $today; ?>,
    'end': <?php echo $date1; ?>,
    'now': <?php echo  $today; ?>,
                    seconds: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,153,102,1)',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    minutes: {
        borderColor: '#ACC742',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    hours: {
        borderColor: '#ECEFCB',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    days: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,153,102,1)',
        borderWidth: '20'
        },callback : functions(){
            'alert("Hie")'      

        }
        //  if('end' >= 'start')
        //$("body").load(retreive.php?<?php //echo $_GET['g']?>)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [this](https://github.com/PragmaticMates/jquery-final-countdown) plugin, then the second argument when calling it is the callback function to execute on completion of the countdown:

```
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
    start: <?php echo  $today; ?>,
    end: <?php echo $date1; ?>,
    now: <?php echo  $today; ?>,
    seconds: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,153,102,1)',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    minutes: {
        borderColor: '#ACC742',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    hours: {
        borderColor: '#ECEFCB',
        borderWidth: '15'
    },
    days: {
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,153,102,1)',
        borderWidth: '20'
    }
}, function() {
    console.log('countdown completed');
    // Do something...
});
```